# Draw a trapezoid in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, transformation

Could somebody advice how to transform image on canvas from rectangle to trapeze?

For example I have a image-rectangle 100x200 and canvas 300x300.
Then I want to transform my image and put corners in the following points:
100,0; 200,0;
0,300; 300,300
And transformation should re-size image to fit new figure.

Comment: I believe trapezoid is the word you're looking for?

Comment: @Chris: I thought so too!  I googled it an turns out "trapeze" is actually a specific kind of trapezoid -- I guess we learn something new every day!

Comment: @markE Do you have a citation on that? I see no such thing.

Comment: [Chuckling at myself after taking a second look]  Trapeze is the greek root for trapezoid: http://www.mathopenref.com/trapezoid.html.  But since I don't speak greek, I think I'll just call it a trapezoid like everyone else! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get it, you want to do a y-rotation (like the star wars scrolling intro).

**Not possible with the current canvas 2d context transform matrix**

The 2d transformation matrix looks like this with the last values fixed at 0,0,1:

M11, M21, dx

M12, M22, dy

0, 0, 1

You would need a y-rotation matrix that looks like this:

cosA, 0, sinA

0, 1, 0

-sinA, 0, cosA

But you can't set -sinA, 0, cosA

[Previous answer]

**Here's how you change an rectangle-containing-image to a trapezoid-containing-image**

You have to draw each leg of the trapeze individually. But you can draw 3 of the sides and then use closePath() to automatically draw the 4th side.

This code animates between the rectangle and the trapezoid and scales the clipped image.  This code assumes you want the image presented in a way that keeps the scaling image as large as possible.

Here's code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/7T2YQ/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px;}
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.lineWidth=5;

        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
          return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
          function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
        })();

        var left=1.0;
        var right=300;
        var sizing=.25;

        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){
          animate();
        }
        img.src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/KoolAidMan.png";

        function animate() {

          // update scaling factors
          left+=sizing;
          right-=sizing;
          if(left<0 || left>100){sizing = -sizing;}
          console.log(left+"/"+right);


          // clear and save the context
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          ctx.save();

          // draw the clipping trapezoid
          defineTrapezoid(left,right);
          ctx.clip();

          // draw trapezoid border
          defineTrapezoid(left,right);
          ctx.stroke();

          // draw image clipped in trapeze
          var imgX=left/2;
          var imgY=left;
          var w=300-left;
          ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,imgX,imgY,w,w);

          ctx.restore();

          // request new frame
          requestAnimFrame(function() {
            animate();
          });
        }
        animate();

        function defineTrapezoid(left,right){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(left,0);
            ctx.lineTo(right,0);
            ctx.lineTo(300,300);
            ctx.lineTo(0,300);
            ctx.closePath();
        }        

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I need to scale image.

Comment: I changed the code: now transforms an image-rectangle to an image-trapezoid.  Is this what you need?

Comment: Thank you for trying but it is actually not what I want. I need a function that helps me to transform texture in trapeziod depends on coordinates, I trying to render a globe and as closer you comes to pole as much square texture becomes a trapeze. Something like this - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49697996/Untitled.png (orange border means that I do not want to crop an image but I want move corners). Thank you in advance.